# How can I make a swap on raydium using typescript on devnet?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, typescript, swap, raydium

My end goal is to create a swap script, where user have SOL, if he does not hold WSOL it get's wrapped into it and then gets swapped with user's entered token address.
Can someone help me out?